# C:\phpunittest>./vendor/bin/phpunit commnd is not working

Tags: phpunit

when i run C:\phpunittest>./vendor/bin/phpunit on cmd,it does not work in the expected way.It shows  '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file on console.what can i do now?

Comment: Try with  `.\vendor\bin\phpunit` or simply `vendor\bin\phpunit` (verify also the file exists on the dir).

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
.\vendor\bin\phpunit
```

or simply

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```